# How to create physical menu button (like the one in Android) menu in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, android-menu

I am developing a navigation based application in iPhone.

In which I want to create physical menu button like menu like the one in Android phones.

The menu can be accessed from any view in the hierarchy.

Do any one have any idea how can we achieve this .

Can we add a drawer like menu to UINavigationBar ?

Please don't suggest the tabbarcontroller as it is the last option.

Comment: How can anything that is drawn onscreen be physical? You want something like Android's notification pulldown?

Comment: yes some thing like that which is accessible throughout the navigation

Comment: Have you seen iOS 5? It does something similar, so you won't be able to use that gesture for your own ui. How about you tell us what is it exactly that you want to do first and we suggest you how to do it?

Comment: @fichek Have you seen the actionsheet like menu that comes up in android on clicking the physical menu button ? I want to do something similar  to that ... please give me any idea that supports ios > 3.0 as many people still using iphone 3g or 3gs.

Comment: I guess UIActionSheet doesn't fit your needs? How do you want to activate this sheet? Using a button on your toolbar/navbar?

Comment: I do not want to user uiactionsheet . I am just want to show an idea (like that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is create a subclass of `UIViewController`, e.g. `MasterViewController`. Have all of the view controllers subclass `MasterViewController`. In the `MasterViewController` you can write code to create and display your drawer view, and then all of your view controllers will inherit that code and can call it on themselves at any point.

To slide the view in:

`drawerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -1*drawerView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, whateverHeight);`
`[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];`
`drawerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, whateverHeight);`
`[UIView commitAnimations];`

Comment: I think your idea is also innovative

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but probably not the best.  You will potentially lose data on the `drawerView` between view loads.

Comment: You could move the drawerView to a singleton I suppose and keep the code for displaying it in the MasterViewController.

Comment: My main concern is the drawer actions not the data for now... I want to change the current view hierarchy from the drawer . so probably this is the best one as far as to support older os versions also. you should support that too .

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is just set the titleView of UINavigationItem to an arbitrary UIView to handle user taps.

This doesn't have to be a text label :)

Comment: I think I can combine your and Mohammad's answers to get the solution .It is somehow very near to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

If that's the case then I'd suggest you taking `sharedInstance` with flags tracking the hierarchy of the view controller stack. Every time  when user navigate just update your `sharedInstance` and do the custom menu preparation and populate it. The good practice would be reuse your UI component rather than making it new on every navigation operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "`DrawerView`" class and import it into where you will want to use it. Then you can use `presentModalViewController: myDrawer` to make it appear when you need it. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: hey WrightCS thanks for your quick suggestion . But for your idea I have to call presentModalViewController in every controller in the heirarchy instead I want a drawer that is embeded in the uinavigationbar and can call like tapping on the uinavigationbar or pulling with a handle like uinavigationbar category

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple..

In one XIB u can add many views right. now add two main views like say data view and down side button view u want in. (if m nt wronge with 4 buttons to navigate) now keep ur this view at top . and all the other hirarchy of views u can add in that data view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a singleton `UIViewController` or `UIView` for this. Advantage of the `UIViewController` is that it can be presented with the `presentModalViewController:animated:` method, and also if you need, you can push it to your navigation stack. Also an advantage that you have a `UIView` instance in the same time.
Using the singleton pattern, you can reach your class anywhere.

Check this link from the official documentation about singleton in objective-c: [Creating a Singleton Instance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32)
Or you can use Matt Gallagher's macro (because this is very comfortable to use): [Singleton macro](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you can get iOS 5 beta, I highly recommend it.  The new beta dev release has an extension on `UIViewController`, dubbed by Apple as container view controllers.  They are very easy to set up, and I am using one in my app.

Container view controllers work like `UINavigationControllers` and `UITabBarControllers` in that they allow you to add child view *controllers*, not just child views.  Like I've said, they are simple to set up.  I'll explain how:

1. Create a new class called `ContainerController`.  Add an initialization method called `- (id)initWithNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)controller`.  It's implementation should look something like this:

   ```
   if ((self = [super init])) {
     [self addChildViewController:controller];
     controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420); // Leave room for the menu at bottom of the screen
     [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
   }
   ```

   The reason we are adding a navigation controller is because it keeps this container controller from doing transitions, which is more complicated.
2. In the `ContainerController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, create the menu:

   ```
   [super viewDidLoad];

   UIView *menuWrapperView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
   menuWrapperView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 420, 320, 40); // Place a wrapper for the menu buttons directly below the navigation controller

   UIButton *button1 = ...;
   UIButton *button2 = ...;

   [menuWrapperView addSubview:button1];
   [menuWrapperView addSubview:button2];

   [self.view addSubview:menuWrapperView];
   ```

With this approach (using child view controllers), your views and navigation controller will get their needed memory warning, view loading, and rotation handling method calls when needed.

Comment: what if I have to support 3.1.3 as deployment target

Comment: Sorry, but this solution won't work in that case.  You _could_, however, whack all the child view controller code and just add the views to the `ContainerController`, but you'd lose the `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, etc. calls.

Comment: Practically though, intentionally *not* using new APIs, even when they are needed, is probably a really bad idea.