# iOS 5 Keep a consistent tab bar across multiple scenes

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uitabbar

I am developing my first Apple product on iOS 5. What is the best way to maintain a consistent UITabBar object across multiple scenes when I'm *not* using the UITabBarController? It's just a standard UIViewController. I have the tab bar working just as I want it on one scene and I want to be able to duplicate it to my other 4-ish scenes.

Comment: Just out of interest, why not using a UITabBarController?

Comment: 3 words. Framework fight club.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304388/how-to-create-physical-menu-button-like-the-one-in-android-menu-in-iphone/7430533#7430533).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you really don't want to use a `UITabViewController`, then have your application delegate maintain a reference to your global `UITabBar` object and as you switch from view to view, you can just request that instance and add it the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`UIAppearance`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) API to set your visual properties on all `UITabBar` instances.

```
id appearance = [UITabBar appearance];
[appearance setBackgroundImage:someImage];
[appearance setTintColor:someTintColor];
//...
```

[Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007521-CH3-SW4)'s a list of the properties that can be set on `UITabBar`'s `UIAppearance` proxy:

Answer (score 1):

I think this innovative Answer will use for you
[Physical Button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7406944/559005)

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple and easy to do (I've done it in multiple apps).

1. Create a view based application. Let's call the single VC thus created as "MainViewController".
2. Create your top-bar with images, buttons and what have you in MainViewController.xib. Set the background color of the top level UIView as "Clear Color".
3. Add nothing else to this xib.
4. Create View Controllers and Xibs for the all the views that you need
   to show (including the initial/first view). Let's call them MyViewController1 & MyViewController2.
5. Let MainViewController have "has a" relationship with MyViewController1. Meaning MainViewController will have a member variable/property of the type MyViewController1.
6. Ditto for MyViewController2.
7. Instantiate MyViewController1 & 2 in "viewDidLoad" method of MainViewController.
8. Add them as subviews of MainViewController.
9. Add the hidden property to NO for the initial view (MyViewController1 maybe) and YES for the other one.
10. At this point, you'll see the top-bar of the MainViewController and the MyViewController1's view under it.
11. When you need to switch to MyViewController2, just set set its hidden property to NO, and MyViewController1's hidden property to YES.
12. If you'd like to animate the transition from MyViewController1 to
     MyViewController2, add the  CABasicAnimation/CATransition to
     CALayers to MyViewController1 & MyViewController2 (and not the
     MainViewController). Then your top-bar (drawn on
     MainViewController) will remain rock-solid stable and the
     MyViewController1 & 2 will switch/animate under it.
13. If however, you'd like the top-bar to go away and the new top-bar to show up along with the next view, just attach CATransition/CAAnimation etc. to the CALayer of MainViewController.

Feel free to ask any questions.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use a view to wrap the content you want to be dynamic. Then you could add the first visible view as a subview of this view. Next you would need to animate a transition between the views ( the current view, and the one you want to change to ) to simulate changing a view controller. Here is code that I have used that does this between two views. My "wrapper" view is called content view. You would need to integrate this with what tab bar you have setup...

```
[ contentView addSubview:view2 ];
[ view1 removeFromSuperview ];

CATransition *animation = [ CATransition animation ];

[ animation setType:kCATransitionPush ];
[ animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromRight ];
[ animation setDuration:0.5 ];
[ animation 
 setTimingFunction:[ CAMediaTimingFunction
                    functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut
  ]
 ];

[[ contentView layer ]
 addAnimation:animation
 forKey:@"currentTransition"
 ];
```

Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the Standard way but if you really want to give tabBar functionality in your application without using the tabBar.

Create a 4-5 custom buttons(with images) at the bottom of every view (size 199 X 49 ) so that it entirely consume the bottom of the view (like tabBar).Give only one of the buttons action in a one view rest all are disabled. Also the button function you give should change the image to show that the current tab is clicked.